# Proxy SQL Error "Detected a broken connection during SET NAMES"

Tags: mysql, proxysql

i am testing proxysql cache functionality but i got this error.

My idea is to use proxysql to decrease the load on the remote database server.

```
2021-04-08 13:50:42 MySQL_Session.cpp:2543:handler_again___status_CHANGING_CHARSET(): [ERROR] Detected a broken connection during SET NAMES on 66.97.38.58 , 3306 : 2019, Can't initialize character set (null) (path: compiled_in)
Can't initialize character set (null) (path: compiled_in)
2021-04-08 13:50:42 MySQL_Session.cpp:2543:handler_again___status_CHANGING_CHARSET(): [ERROR] Detected a broken connection during SET NAMES on 66.97.38.58 , 3306 : 2019, Can't initialize character set (null) (path: compiled_in)
```

On the local server I run these versions.

```
# ProxySQL version 2.0.6

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'mysql-default_charset';
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| mysql-default_charset | utf8  |
+-----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select hostgroup_id, hostname, status  from runtime_mysql_servers; 
+--------------+-------------+--------+
| hostgroup_id | hostname    | status |
+--------------+-------------+--------+
| 1            | 66.97.x.x | ONLINE |
+--------------+-------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


# MySQL Ver 8.0.2

mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_system     | utf8                           |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I have already read several publications about the error but the truth is I do not know how to solve it.

## Remote Server

```
MySQL 5.7.32

mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Any ideas??

Regards,